# How can I have Bitcoind.exe use the core data from Bitcoin-QT on my D drive. Using Windows 10

Tags: bitcoind, windows, daemon

I down loaded Bitcoin core to my D drive, because it's too big for my C drive. Bitcoind.exe keeps creating AppData/Roaming/bitcoin where the core is down loaded. However I already have the core fully down loaded to my "D:/Bitcoin Core data" What commands can I put into command line in Windows to direct bitcoind.exe to continue to write to the D Drive.  Also how would I create a short cut to replicate this with out having to always type it in the command line.

Is there any way to automate the process.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do it one of which is modifying the shortcut as you've mentioned.

The easiest way is to create a bitcoin.conf file in **%APPDATA%\Bitcoin**. That's the default directory bitcoind will look for a configuration file.

Based on your question you can set the contents of bitcoin.conf to:

```
datadir=D:\Bitcoin Core data
```